# Bottle Printing on Page

Tags: python, bottle

Whenever I need to print a message on the HTML page, I have to return that message from the function. For example :
`return "Hello World"`. How should I print within the HTML code without the return statement?

Comment: already tried using templates ?

Comment: Have  you tried the proposed solution using templates ?

Answer (score 0):

Bottle make usage of templates to create structured web pages.

Here it is a sample

Here is an example template:

```
%if name == 'World':
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    <p>This is a test.</p>
%else:
    <h1>Hello {{name.title()}}!</h1>
    <p>How are you?</p>
%end
```

All you have to do is to provide the name of the template and the variables you want to pass to the template as keyword arguments. Here’s a simple example of how to render a template:

```
@route('/hello')
@route('/hello/<name>')
@view('hello_template')
def hello(name='World'):
    return dict(name=name)
```

Documentation here: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html